# Execute check on each page request (not every controller action)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an external API check that I want to execute each time a user does requests a page on my site. However I don't want to execute the check every time an action is called - there are quite a lot of partial views, Html.Actions and ajax controller action calls in the views, and checking the API multiple times a page will slow the application down.

I've tried overriding `OnActionExecuting` in my base controller, but that obviously fires every time an action is called, meaning it will fire on partials, etc.

I've also tried implementing Application_`AcquireRequestState` in `global.asax` but this is called multiple times per page, as well.

I was wondering if there was a way to only execute a block of code if there has been a full page request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check `if (!ControllerContext.IsChildAction)`

Answer (score 0):

Set a `bool` saying that it has been executed to the `HttpContext.Items` collection. Check for the `bool` before executing the code.

The `HttpContext.Items` collection lives for the duration of a single request.